# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Finder' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna display all files of a directory in the laravel application here is the error occurs about Finder can anyone help me with this.

Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Finder' not found

Code

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Resource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Finder;

public function index()

    {   
        $dir=base_path('resources/views/t/');
        return view('/admin/fileshandel/index')->with('allfiles' , 
        iterator_to_array(Finder::create()->files()->in($dir), false));
    }
```

Comment: You can check all the available classes here: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Facades.html There isn't a `Finder` class. (Note: Check `5.9` and `dev` versions also)

Comment: thanks for your comment problem solved. I want one more thing this code now shows me filename with the whole URL but I wanna display only file name?? do you know how can I do this.

Comment: Nope, no idea. If you have a new question, ask a new question. This one has an answer, so accept that one (when you can) to close this. Best to keep questions focused.

Comment: ok also done only using {{basename($name);}}

Answer (score 1):

`Finder` is under the `Symfony` namespace.

`use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;` would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Finder` facade in laravel from version *4.0* till *5.8*, if you need `Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder` is used by the `File` facade in this functions:

```php
/**
 * Get an array of all files in a directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $directory
 * @param  bool  $hidden
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo[]
 */
public function files($directory, $hidden = false){}

/**
 * Get all of the files from the given directory (recursive).
 *
 * @param  string  $directory
 * @param  bool  $hidden
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo[]
 */
public function allFiles($directory, $hidden = false){}

/**
 * Get all of the directories within a given directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $directory
 * @return array
 */
public function directories($directory){}
```

So you can use these functions:

```
File::files($directory, $hidden = false);
File::allFiles($directory, $hidden = false);
File::directories($directory);
```

AFAIR even `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Resource` does not exist in laravel.

To get all files and directories in a directory you can try this:

```
$files = File::files(base_path('resources/views/t/'));
$directories = File::directories(base_path('resources/views/t/'));
```

Comment: well, thanks if I wanna show directories as well as files how can I do this?

Comment: @BilawalAwan please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it solves your question.